# C- Makefile for the entire folder

Tags: c, makefile

I have been using a makefile for my c++ projects. However I tried to convert it into C and tried to compile with gcc and getting a such error: `make: *** No rule to make target`*.o', needed by `microc'.  Stop.`

This is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=*.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=microc

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *o microc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `SOURCES=*.c`.  That just sets the variable to the string `*.c`, so OBJECTS is the string `*.o`.  You want (assuming you're using GNU make):

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
```

Comment: gcc -c -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic os_q.c -o os_q.o
os_q.c:25:21: ucos_ii.h: No such file or directory
os_q.c:1: warning: ISO C forbids an empty source file
makefile:14: recipe for target `os_q.o' failed
make: *** [os_q.o] Error 1

Still cannot link them

Comment: @SarpKaya - That's a totally different problem. It's correctly finding your target now, but not compiling. This has nothing to do with make anymore. Looks like youneed to find the ucos_ii.h header file and make sure it's in your project

Comment: @Mike, I downloaded this online and I have to compile, it just does not come with a makefile. ucos_ii.h header file is in the folder already!

Comment: @SarpKaya , that is the error echoed by gcc not the make utility , so write a makefile for a simple hello world program first and understand it, before you move on to bigger projects..

Comment: Check the includes : using quotes or brackets? If it's the latter one, you might need to add -I. or similar.